# Network traffic being filtered on OVH Public Cloud's Private Network

Tags: pfsense, openstack, ovh

We are currently attempting to set up an isolated infrastructure separate from the WAN using a firewall (pfsense) and private networks. We are experiencing connectivity issues on the virtual network we have established between the firewall and our applications.

Pfsense can connect to the internet.

[Pfsense Connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ5H4.png)

But the application server cannot ping the internet, and VPN clients are also unable to reach the application server.

[Splunk Connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6410.png)

[VPN Connectivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fPAC.png)

We have used TCPdump on the firewall's interface connected to the private network and observed that packets are being routed to the application server but never reach their destination. The default (and only) security group is supposed to allow all traffic. There are no firewall rules on the application server.

[TCPdump splunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVAy3.png)

[TCPdump vpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBUvz.png)

[security_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA7YL.png)

[splunk FW rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTIES.png)

It appears that something is filtering the private network. Is our implementation feasible in the Public Cloud, or is this due to a configuration error?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste. It just makes it harder to extract information.